# Postgresql forgets grants after recreating tables

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, postgresql-9.3

We use liquibase to manage and execute our database changes. On our DEV environment (and especially on local machines) we frequently recreate the tables to have a clean slate.
We have just migrated from MySQL to Postgres and are facing a problem related to these table recreations.

Initially we have granted our DB user with this:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mydbuser;
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO mydbuser;
```

This is executed through *psql* after connecting to our own DB (where public is the default/only schema).

Everything is fine until we ask liquibase to recreate the tables in which case it will drop all tables and create them again.

After that it appears that *mydbuser* has lost all its grants on the tables.

According to several resources (like [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)) we need to alter the default privileges, so we obey:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mydbuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON TABLES TO mydbuser;

GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO mydbuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO mydbuser;
```

However, although this seems very logical it changed nothing. All grants (even select) are still lost after recreating the tables.

What are we doing wrong or what else do we need to do?

**UPDATE**

\ddp shows:
             Default access privileges

> Owner   | Schema |   Type   | Access privileges
>   ----------+--------+----------+--------------------
>      postgres | public | sequence | mydb=rU/postgres
>      postgres | public | table    | mydb=arwd/postgres

Comment: +1. I never got this to work either. I've always assumed it was a bug that would eventually get fixed. Apparently not, or then it has yet to be reported.

Comment: Nothing wrong in what's shown but there's too much missing. Who's the owner of the objects? Is the same user issuing the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...`? What happens between this command and the recreation of the objects? What does `\dddp` in psql report before recreating the tables?

Comment: @Daniel: the default postgres user is the owner, _\dddp_ (Object descriptions) returns no results (0 rows).

Comment: ... and the postgres user is executing all above commands.

Comment: sorry, I meant `\ddp` (default access privilege settings)

Comment: \ddp returned results, see update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If trying to mimic what liquibase is doing in a simplified test case, it just works.

Quick demo with 9.3:

1) Create the objects from scratch with the `postgres` user:

```
postgres=# create database dbtest;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# create user mydbuser;
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# \c dbtest
You are now connected to database "dbtest" as user "postgres".

dbtest=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON TABLES TO mydbuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES

dbtest=# create table foobar(id int);
CREATE TABLE
```

2) In another session let's connect with `mydbuser` and see if SELECT is allowed.

```
dbtest=> select * from foobar;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Result: Yes, it's allowed. Note the result of `\ddp` too:

```
dbtest=> \ddp
             Default access privileges
  Owner   | Schema | Type  |   Access privileges    
----------+--------+-------+------------------------
 postgres | public | table | mydbuser=arwd/postgres
(1 row)
```

3) Let's have `postgres` drop the table and recreate it:

```
dbtest=# drop table foobar;
DROP TABLE
dbtest=# create table foobar(id int);
CREATE TABLE
```

4) See if `mydbuser` can still SELECT from it.

```
$ psql -d dbtest -U mydbuser
dbtest=> select * from foobar;
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Result: Yes, as expected.

5) See if another user can SELECT from it.

```
$ psql -d dbtest -U daniel
dbtest=> select * from foobar;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation foobar
```

Result: No, as expected.

This does not explain what doesn't work for you, but you may compare the above with the set of commands issued by liquibase.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to do the same exercise.

Comment: Above works fine for me as well and I think I found the cause of the problem. The tables are actually not created by the postgres user but by another super user (jenkins). If I do a select on any table created by that user I get permission denied; it works fine for tables created by the postgres user. Not yet sure however what the solution is. Have the jenkins user grant the rights?

Comment: @stijn: having jenkins issuing the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES...` should work. I think the point is this sentence in the doc: _You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of_

Comment: That seems to have done the trick; not sure however is this is the way to go, it does not seem very clean but we can live with it.